# Prevent multiple threads to access only one element of an array (instead of whole the array)

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I would like to calculate a **two dimensional float array** 'Image2D' and do this faster by using '**OpenMP**' to execute the outer for-loop in **parallel**.

In the loops, the position '[jy][jx]' inside 'Image2D' gets calculated. So, it is possible that, at the **same moment**, two (or more) threads want to increment 'Image2D' at the **same position** '[jy][jx]'. Of what I understood (but you may correct me) in that case only one increment is performed while the other increment is lost.

To avoid this, I thought to add the line of code '#pragma omp critical'. It makes sure only one thread can read/increment/write the variable 'Image2D'.

Unfortunately, this means that when a first thread is accessing 'Image2D', the other threads must **wait** until the first finished its job. For my code, this will **slow down** the execution tremendously because 'Image2D' is accessed all the time.

Moreover '#pragma omp critical' is **too strict**: it prevents multiple threads to access the **whole array** 'Image2D' while it is sufficient to prevent access to **one element** of 'Image2D' (i.e. one position 'Image2D[jy][jx]').

So, my question is: Is there a way to
 (i) prevent multiple threads to write 'Image2D[jy][jx]' at the same time;
(ii) without letting the threads wait for each other unnecessarily and hence obtain fast code.

Thank you for your answer

```
    #pragma omp parallel private(  ia, iR, Cte, jjx, jx,jy )
    {   // start parallel
    #pragma omp for
    for ( ia = i0a; ia <= i1a; ia++ ) {
            // ... code removed ....
            for ( iR = i0R; iR <= i1R; iR++ ) {
                    // ... code removed ....
                    // 'Cte' (float) and 'jjx' (float) are computed
                    for ( jy = j0y; jy <= j1y; jy++ ) {
                            // ... code removed ...
                            // 'jx' (int) gets computed
                            #pragma omp critical
                            Image2D[jy][jx] +=  Cte * (  1.0 - ( jjx - jx )  );     // increment 'Image2D[jy][jx]'
                            // ... code removed ....
                    } // Next 'jy'
            } // Next 'iR'
     }// Next 'ia'
     }// end parallel section
```

Comment: The problem is not a lost increment, it is that the whole program is nonsense, aka. undefined behavior. As far as I can tell you can parallelize the inner for-loop since the loops all access different indexes. Assuming `j1y` is bigger than the number of cores you have that could be sufficient.

Comment: You could not know, because I removed part of the code, but it is **not** possible to parallelise the **inner** for-loop: 'jjx' is updated **in**side this inner for-loop.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. However, saying that the 'whole program is nonsens', does not help me further.

Comment: The nonsense part was so you take a race condition more serious. A lost increment isn't so bad, undefined behavior is. From the code you have shown all I can say is try to separate the image into independent blocks and parallelize those. Maybe you can move the `jjx` calculation outside the loop. If that is not possible you can make a `jx`x`jy` mutex array and acquire a mutex for every image access, which is only worth it if calculating the increment value takes a long time. Maybe you can imagine a chess pattern on the image and update first the black and then the white squares.Need more detail

Comment: All I can think of is making `Image2D` a `private` variable, call it `Image2D0`. When you are done with the computations sum `Image2D0` accross all threads. This avoids the need for `OMP critical` and thus should be faster. Effectively `Image2D` should be a `reduction` the problem is that it is an array which is not allowed for reductions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about OpenMP, but it's sounding like it's not quite giving you the level of control that you want.

As PetrH suggests the best answer maybe to have a private array per thread, then sum those arrays afterwards. Even that can be parallelised.

That'll work quite well provided you have the memory for it. If not you might have to consider an alternative. That could involve mutex semaphores.

Obviously your 2D array is sufficiently large to require OpenMP, so a mutex per cell is likely going to be wasteful. You could have a mutex per row, or one per 10 rows, etc. The fewer mutexes the greater the chance of two threads contending for the same group of cells. Also, whilst you would be taking and giving the mutex once per loop iteration (and calculating which mutex too), OSes nowadays go to a lot of effort to make mutex semaphore system calls fast. It could be that a little extra CPU time per thread gives you the scheduling you want and thus the overall benefit might be good.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the issue, as you suggested, by calculating 'Image2D' for every thread separately and sum them together at the end.
I do not like however, the solution to make 'Image2D' private: Will this not just make, for every thread, a copy of the **pointer** 'Image2D' instead of allocating physical memory for the whole 2D array?

Even if OpenMP would be smart enough to allocate memory for 'Image2D', you would loose time allocating and deallocating memory all the time.

Comment: Therefore I allocate at the start a 3D array 'Image3D' (an 'Image2D' for all the threads) and then, inside the parallel for-loop, I store the results for 'Image2D' in 'Image3D[omp_get_thread_num()]'. When the parallel for-loop is finished, I can sum all the threads together into 'Image2D'.
Is this a good solution?